Using SSL server certificate with only public key
I am new to SoapUI and I want to create a SOAP request with two different certificates:
private certificate (file .pfx) for signing,
SSL server certificate (.cer) with public key, used for data encryption.
With the first one I have no issues, I import it in Keystores and use it for signing parts of the message. However, I cannot import SSL server certificate to Keystores since it has no password - I get the following error:
Private key missing (bad password?) 

How to use public certificate with SoapUI? Also, I had to install  self-signed Certification authority to my computer to make the private certificate (used for signing) work with my C# program. Should I do anything with this regard in SoapUI also?
Any help would be appreciated.

Do you want to use the private key for request signing or TLS mutual certificate based authentication?

Private key for signing, TLS mutual certificate for encryption of the data.

TLS mutual authentication requires a client certificate + private key and for validating the server you may use a server certificate. Thus I think your assumption private key for signing is wrong it makes more sense to use the private key+cert for TLS client authentication.
